Which path use in the Binary Path pgAdmin configuration
I have pgAdmin installed on my personal computer and it's connected to a remote PostgreSQL database. When I tried to backup a table an alert dialog showed:

'/usr/bin/pg_dump' file not found.
Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog

Maybe this is a dumb question but: does the path that pgAdmin expects have to be located in the remote server or my localhost?
I want to know what path pgAdmin is expecting.

Read the docs PATHS.

It is on your local computer. If that happens to be a Windows machine, the path could be something like
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\bin


I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks for your answer Laurenz!

I have fixed the answer.

pgAdmin ships latest PG binaries by default with the desktop version. No need to change bin path in that case. Check the preferences - https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/8.12/preferences.html#the-paths-node
